# Coded UI "You do not have sufficient privileges to access the information about this control or the control is part of the recorder process Error

Tags: coded-ui-tests

Hi I am using Coded UI on a desktop application. I am trying to record a button and I keep getting this error on the Coded UI build tool.

"You do not have sufficient privileges to access the information about this control or the control is part of the recorder process

I am running as admin on my account also.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running your desktop app AND Visual Studio as Admin? These threads seem to indicate the problem is when your application and VS are running at different access levels.

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/244741/Getting-Error-in-CodedUITest-not-have-sufficient-p

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fca108bf-6826-403f-87a6-7de3566141f1/cuittestbuilder-error-you-do-not-have-sufficient-permission-to-access-information-about-this?forum=vsautotest